# How do I define many to many associations and the related properties in Rails (Active record)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, model-associations

I am wondering how do I add additional properties to a many to many relationship.
I have two models that share a many to many relationship, Company and Profession.

Many professionals could belong to a Company

So my Company model looks like below

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :professions
end
```

The same people in the same profession could belong to multiple companies as well
so

```
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

Now I need to associate an hourly rate which could be different for each of the companies for the same profession. I am not very sure where to introduce the hourly rate property? Even if I were to add that to the joining table, how do I access that rate using active record?

Comment: You cannot add more properties through HABTM. Check this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780798/has-and-belongs-to-many-vs-has-many-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical scenario where you select has_many through over habtm.  As a rule, if you only need to associate two models, no other info needed to be stored in the association, use habtm.  For most cases, you have to use has_many through.  You case falls under this scenario.

You want to save the hourly rate in the table that associates a `Profession` and a `Company`.  If you have existing data that you want to migrate, you may want to look at this post [How to migrate has_and_belongs_to_many to has_many through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159134/how-to-migrate-has-and-belongs-to-many-to-has-many-through).  If you can drop the joins table you use for the habtm association, just drop it and create a new table.